# ng2-bootstrap modal hides scroll bar

Tags: modal-dialog, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a modal for my application. I am using ng2-bootstrap of valor-software. Whenever the modal shows, it hides the scroll bar of the webpage and the backdrop takes the whole browser area. Due to it, the content shown in the background shifts to the right. And when i close the modal the scroll bar appears and the content shifts to its original place. I do not want my content to move right and left whenever i open the modal. Is this a bug or is there a way to make it so that the scroll bar does not get hidden when the modal opens? Please kindly point me in the right direction.